# How can I initialize array in a C++11 style?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16239446/3811990) says that C++11 has new feature which allows us to initialize "variable-sized arrays" like this:

```
auto array = new double[M][N]();
```

But when I try to do this, I get following error:

```
array size in new-expression must be constant
```

I didn't forget to add `-std=c++0x` in the .pro file. I tested another C++11 features and it works just fine.

Was he wrong? Or am I?

Thanks.

Comment: In the answer you cite, `M` and `N` are in fact constants. The answer is about that pair of parens at the end which causes the array to be zero-initialized (which I don't believe is new in C++11, either).

Comment: You declared `const auto M, N`?

Comment: Read the answers to the post you linked carefully. Also, this hasn't changed between C++03 and C++11.

Comment: What is this question about? Firstly, C++ does not have variable-sized arrays. A feature vaguely similar to C VLA exists in modern C++, but it is much more restrictive. You can't create multi-dimensional variable-sized arrays in C++. Secondly, the *initialization* syntax you used dates back to the very beginning - C++98 - and has nothing to do with C++11. Thirdly, the only C++11 thing you have there is `auto`, but it has nothing to do with *initialization*. So, what is this question about exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ does not have such unrestricted run-time sized arrays. C++11 introduced a feature remotely similar to C VLAs, but it is significantly more limited. You are not allowed to have VLA of VLAs in C++, meaning that the second, third and further dimensions of any multi-dimensional array in C++ must be constant expressions.

Apparently, this is the requirement you violated. Your `N` is not a constant expression.

In any case, the title of your question talks about *initialization*, while in reality the problem you experienced is not related to initialization at all. The initialization syntax you used - `()` - is not new for C++11, it existed in C++ since the very first language standard.

The only C++11 feature in your code is the above usage of `auto`. But it has nothing to do with initialization or arrays specifically.

Comment: I've mistakenly missed ``const`` keyword, bc of the beginning of the answer. I'm sorry for that, you're right. I will use 2D vector.